# Why would the loss decrease while the accuracy stays the same?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am training a normal feed-forward network on financial data of the last 90 days of a stock, and I am predicting whether the stock will go up or down on the next day. I am using binary cross entropy as my loss and standard SGD for the optimizer. When I train, the training and validation loss continue to go down as they should, but the accuracy and validation accuracy stay around the same.

Here's my model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 90, 256)           1536
_________________________________________________________________
elu (ELU)                    (None, 90, 256)           0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 23040)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 23040)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              23593984
_________________________________________________________________
elu_1 (ELU)                  (None, 1024)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 512)               524800
_________________________________________________________________
elu_2 (ELU)                  (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 512)               262656
_________________________________________________________________
elu_3 (ELU)                  (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 512)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 256)               131328
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 256)               0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 514
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 2)                 0
_________________________________________________________________
Total params: 24,514,818
Trainable params: 24,514,818
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I expect that either both losses should decrease while both accuracies increase, or the network will overfit and the validation loss and accuracy won't change much. Either way, shouldn't the loss and its corresponding accuracy value be directly linked and move inversely to each other?

Also, I notice that my validation loss is always less than my normal loss, which seems wrong to me.

Here's the loss (Normal: Blue, Validation: Green)

[image: Loss]

Here's the accuracy (Normal: Black, Validation: Yellow):

[image: Accuracy]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Loss and accuracy are indeed connected, but the relationship is not so simple.

### Loss drops but accuracy is about the same

Let's say we have 6 samples, our `y_true` could be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Furthermore, let's assume our network predicts following probabilities:

```
[0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
```

This gives us loss equal to `~24.86` and accuracy equal to zero as every sample is wrong.

Now, after parameter updates via backprop, let's say new predictions would be:

```
[0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]
```

One can see those are better estimates of true distribution (loss for this example is `16.58`), while accuracy didn't change and is still zero.

All in all, the relation is more complicated, network could fix its parameters for some examples, while destroying them for other which keeps accuracy about the same.

### Why my network is unable to fit to the data?

Such situation usually occurs when your data is really complicated (or incomplete) and/or your model is too weak. Here both are the case, financial data prediction has a lot of hidden variables which your model cannot infer. Furthermore, dense layers are not the ones for this task; each day is dependent on the previous values, it is a perfect fit for [Recurrent Neural Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), you can find an article about LSTMs and how to use them [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) (and tons of others over the web).

Comment: First off, thanks for the thorough response, I get what your saying, but as I train the loss goes far down, starting in the thousands and going into the single digits without any affect on the accuracy. Shouldn't the accuracy start to rise if the loss goes that low? My question is if the target is [0, 1] and the network returns [0.2, 0.8] will that be marked as 100% accuracy or 0%, because I'm only doing binary classification and am using binary accuracy.

Comment: With `[0.2, 0.8]` you would get `100%` accuracy, as `0.2` after thresholding at `0.5` will be zero and `0.8` will be 1. Still, this example would have some loss, which would be optimized by the neural network. This optimization step may ruin what the net learned before. You may of it like a Whack a Mole game with samples, when one is learned, another may be unlearned and so on. You definitely should try RNNs or other architectures exploiting structure of the data, this model is way to weak to provide you with anything, for binary classification random guess is `0.5`, exactly like your network.

Comment: Quick question, do I set the threshold somewhere or does it automatically default to 0.5? And in binary classification if it outputs [0.7, 0.8] will that still be 100% accuracy or not. I am trying to implement an RNN right now, I'm hoping it should do much better

Comment: It is set automatically to `0.5` for binary classification and `sigmoid` activation function in your binary cross entropy loss. You round everything up  to the nearest integer (`0` or `1`), and it depends what the true targets were. If there were `[0, 1]` true labels and network outputed `[0.7, 0.8]`, you round those to nearest integer getting `[1., 1.]`. Only second `1` is correct, first prediction should be `0` so the `accuracy` is `0.5` in this case.